# Accessing web application using loopback ipaddress from other server is not working

Tags: java, web-applications, server-side, loopback-address

I have a web application which is running on local, the other wants to access my application in local by using http://127.0.0.1:8080/myWeb/checkSession.
If other server wants to access my local application i am getting the folowing error.

> 127.0.0.1 - connection failed.

Why is this failing?

Answer (score 0):

127.0.0.1 is your local IP. The same as http://localhost:8080/myWeb/checkSession
When a user on another computer uses 127.0.0.1 they try to connect to their computer and not yours.

In order for others to see your application from another computer they need to use your IP address in the outside network. And also your computer needs to be visible to them (not behind firewall etc).